# Jenkins: Delete the only one particular unfinished docker image without tag and name

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have several `parallel` Jenkins jobs, each of which builds an image by a Dockerfile.

If one of the jobs fails, other jobs are interrupted also. And their unfinished images are left untagged and unnamed. So in Jenkins `post` phases of the jobs the unfinished images are not deleted by `docker rmi --force ${env.MODULE_NAME}:${env.IMAGE_TAG}`. This situation leads to eating up space on the Jenkins nodes.

Is there any way to delete this particular unfinished image, if it is left untagged and unnamed? Using labels for example or something like that.

Comment: Is `docker system prune -f` not viable? This also sounds like you have one build agent for this pipeline.

Comment: No, the jobs may be run on the same physical node inside one jenkins build. And several jenkins builds may be launched at once. I don't want to interfere.